# Ansible hostvars variable undefined when debugging/templating etc

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to dynamically generate part of an /etc/hosts file with ansible, by gathering facts from all the hosts and looping through the resulting `hostvars` to grab the IP of the second interface (I need a private IP on this interface, rather than the public IP of the other interface)

I can grab this information from a single host using the following plays:

```
- name: play 1
  hosts: all

- name: play 2
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: no
  tasks:
   - debug:
        var: hostvars['mysinglehost'].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1]
```

...but what I'd like to do is loop through all the hosts and get this value from every host, eventually writing this information to my hosts file, but I'd settle for just getting some debug information :)

I tried

```
...
  - debug:
      var: hostvars[item].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1]
    with_inventory_hostnames:
      - all
...
```

...which gives the output I expect, yet when I try to output a `msg` with this debug task:

```
...
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1] }}"
    with_inventory_hostnames:
      - all
...
```

I get the following error (as I do when I attempt to e.g. write to a file using `lineinfile`):

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, as it's trying to reference the exact same variable. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a complete playbook that reproduces the problem? Based on your description here I tried [this playbook](https://gist.github.com/larsks/fe9b62baadb54e8ca4cc3c3a530d474c), and it runs against my systems without any errors.

Comment: I tried your playbook and get the same error. Works when using `var`, fails with that error when using `msg` and curly brackets. I'm wondering if it's a bug in the version of Ansible I'm using (2.10.5)

Comment: I was testing on 2.9.something. Let me grab 2.10.5 and take a look...

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The play book I posted runs fine with [ansible 2.10.5](https://asciinema.org/a/23d1rAoOjfsyOZAUZSAPWuBHL) and [ansible 2.10.6](https://asciinema.org/a/AMzvqcNWnRQIRa44vaubMor4T).

Comment: What is the target OS of the machine failing ? If linux, is the `ip` command available ? I had the same problem today on a centos 7 docker container and discovered I would not get any network facts without that command available. See the [line in the relevant fact collector](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/1d5110db6fc91aae310c2a916cccf787e18b3011/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/network/linux.py#L49). Installing `iproute` (providing `ip` on centos 7) fixed the issue.

Comment: @Zeitounator, I've confirmed the `ip` command is on those machines. I think the problem comes from trying to parse `hostvars`. I'm starting to think perhaps I've found a bug..?

Comment: The problem is definitely that there is no `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` returned in your facts for that particular host. You can easily confirm this by running `- debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` in your first play which will return `undefinied`. Then you have to understand why (e.g. that host only has ipv6 connectivity, the user running setup does not have access to that info, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but in principle, perhaps this would work?

```
- hosts: all

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      my_hosts: |
        {
          {% for a_host in hostvars | dict2items %}
            "{{ a_host.key }}": "{{ a_host.value.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[1] }}",
          {% endfor %}
        }
```

Then, instead of looping over hostvars, you just loop over `my_hosts`?

Comment: Sorry Jon, I still get `ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute` - I actually tried with something that should just return a single value as well - `ansible_architecture`, and get the same error :(